# Reading a CSV with where some columns have new lines and some columns have 2 double quotes

Tags: apache-spark

I have a CSV where some known columns can have new lines but are quoted with double quotes when there is a new line in the column value. I also might have columns encoded in **two double quotes** like `""Adobe XMP Core 7.0-c000 79.1357c9e, 2021/07/14-00:39:56        ""` where there is a comma in the value. I thought of reading it first as a text file, replacing two double quotes with one double quote, and then parsing it as a CSV. The code is shown below.

```scala
def readTextReplaceQuotesAndParseAsCSV(path: String): DataFrame = {
    //import necessary spark sql types
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

    // read as text file
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(path)

    // replace two double quotes with one
    val replacedRDD = rdd.map(line => line.replaceAll("\"\"", "\""))

    // Creating the Dataset with manual encoding
    val ds = spark.createDataset(replacedRDD)(Encoders.STRING)
    ds.foreach(x => println(x))

    // read Dataset[String] as csv
    val df = spark.read
      .option("header", true)
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .csv(ds)

    df
  }
```

It is solving the problem of replacing two double quotes, but the `multiLine -> true` is not working anymore.

File:

```
id,name,desc,tags,user
1,sam,"quoted two
lines",tag1,tom
2,chuck,""one line, two quotes"",tag1,tom
3,sam,"quoted
three
lines",tag1,tom
```

Output from `ds.foreach(x => println(x))`:

```
id,name,desc,tags,user
1,sam,"quoted two
lines",tag1,tom
2,chuck,"one line, two quotes",tag1,tom
3,sam,"quoted
three
lines",tag1,tom
```

Output from final `df.show()`:

```
+------+-----+--------------------+----+----+
|id    |name |desc                |tags|user|
+------+-----+--------------------+----+----+
|1     |sam  |quoted two          |null|null|
|lines"|tag1 |tom                 |null|null|
|2     |chuck|one line, two quotes|tag1|tom |
|3     |sam  |quoted              |null|null|
|three |null |null                |null|null|
|lines"|tag1 |tom                 |null|null|
+------+-----+--------------------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to go around this by using the [`unescapedQuoteHandling`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) option.

By just reading the CSV file using `spark.read` and the necessary options you can get this:

```scala
val df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("multiline", "true")
  .option("unescapedQuoteHandling", "STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE")
  .csv("./weirdCsv.csv")

scala> df.show(false)
+---+-----+----------------------+----+----+
|id |name |desc                  |tags|user|
+---+-----+----------------------+----+----+
|1  |sam  |quoted two\nlines     |tag1|tom |
|2  |chuck|"one line, two quotes"|tag1|tom |
|3  |sam  |quoted\nthree\nlines  |tag1|tom |
+---+-----+----------------------+----+----+
```

If you want to remove the quotes from the `desc` column, you could do something like this:

```scala
val no_quotes = df.withColumn("desc", regexp_replace(col("desc"), "\"", ""))

scala> no_quotes.show
+---+-----+--------------------+----+----+
| id| name|                desc|tags|user|
+---+-----+--------------------+----+----+
|  1|  sam|   quoted two\nlines|tag1| tom|
|  2|chuck|one line, two quotes|tag1| tom|
|  3|  sam|quoted\nthree\nlines|tag1| tom|
+---+-----+--------------------+----+----+
```

This works in a spark-shell on version `3.4.1`.